# plink from one server to another server sshpass

Tags: ssh, sshpass

i am trying to run a command "df -kh" in linux server(192.168.82.11) from plink application via intermediate linux server(192.168.82.10) like below. But plink command not running, it hangs.

As i dont have direct access to server 192.168.82.11 iam trying run via 192.168.82.10.

plink username@192.168.82.10 -P 22 -pw password -sshlog e:/test.log (sshpass -p 'password' ssh -T username@192.168.82.11;df -kh)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this case

plink -batch username1@192.168.82.10 -P 22 -pw password1 -sshlog t2.log ("sshpass -p ""password1"" ssh -l username1 192.168.82.11 ""df -kh;top -b -d 1 -n 1""") >> t1.txt